# Only show authors with posts

Tags: list-authors

I thought the code below would work... but no dice. Something like "AND post_count > 0"

function contributors() {
    global $wpdb;

```
$authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users WHERE display_name <> 'admin' AND post_count > 0 ORDER BY display_name");

foreach ($authors as $author ) {

echo "<li>";
echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/author/";
the_author_meta('user_nicename', $author->ID);
echo "/\">";
echo get_avatar($author->ID, 12);
echo "</a>";
echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/author/";
the_author_meta('user_nicename', $author->ID);
echo "/\">";
the_author_meta('display_name', $author->ID);
echo "</a>";
echo "</li>";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'author'         => $author->ID
);
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
$count = count( $posts );
```

Put this right after the foreach, $count will now contain either 1 or 0, put it through an if statement to filter the output.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks I tried that and put if ($count = "0") { around the output but nothing changed

Comment: try `if( 0 < $count ) {`, should do you fine. `if( $count = 0 ) {` just executes it if it's capable of setting the count to 0. At the very least you'll need ==, but that will only show authors with no posts, so you want `$count > 0`, but the better way to write this is `0 < $count` (precisely because if you try to say `0 = $count`, PHP will throw an error, so putting the value first became preferred, regardless of operator)

Comment: Figured it out.

I added the following function:

    $post_count = get_usernumposts($author->ID);

And then add an if statement around the output like so:

    if($post_count > 0){

Comment: Good to hear, don't forget to mark the solution for the next person having this problem :)